# How to put javascript into script pages when it contains tag library

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jsp-tags

I am facing a limitation and because of this i have to put all jquery scripts in my jsp pages.

I have lots of code like this

```
$.get("<c:url value="/deletepage" />", {id: id} )
```

I wanted all these code to put into separate js files but since the scripts contains tag libraries i am unable to do it.
Is there any way possible to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can just save the JavaScript files as JSP and set the header to output JavaScript to the browser.

I imagine something like this would do the trick:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: I'm saying you can abstract your code to another jsp file and set the content type to javascript, then include it as a javascript file from your html. Because it's a jsp file, you can keep all your tag libraries.